# How can i add new field in add new product general tab?

Tags: magento

I am working on extension. I need to add new field in add new product general tab.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an install script for your extension with the following code:

```
 $installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$data=array(
    'type'=>'int',
    'input'=>'text', // The type that you want... varchar/boolean...
    'sort_order'=> 1, // YOU MIGHT NEED TO CHANGE THIS VALUE TO PUT THE ATTRIBUTE IN THE FIRST POSITION
    'label'=>'CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE CODE LABEL',
    'global'=>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'required'=>'0',
    'comparable'=>'0',
    'searchable'=>'0',
    'is_configurable'=>'1',
    'user_defined'=>'1',
    'visible_on_front' => 0, //want to show on frontend?
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
    'required'=> 0,
    'unique'=> false,
    'apply_to' => 'configurable', //simple,configurable,bundled,grouped,virtual,downloadable
    'is_configurable' => false
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE',$data);

$installer->addAttributeToSet(
    'catalog_product', 'Default', 'General', 'CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE'
); //Default = attribute set, General = attribute group

$installer->endSetup();
```

Credits: http://ka.lpe.sh/2014/09/04/magento-addremove-product-attribute-programatically/

Comment: This is giving error.....Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`eav_entity_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELET)

Comment: I wrapped the code within startSetup and endSetup, that should solve the problem. Can you retry with the updated code?

Answer (score 1):

```
For creating attibute you need to follow following steps:

1) Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage Attribute in Magento Admin Panel and Create the attribute which you want to show

2) Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage Attribute Set

3) Select the attribute set name like "DEFAULT"

4) Drag your unassigned attribute to Groups section and click Save Attribute Set

5) Flush Cache

6) Do Reindexing

Thats All you need to do.
```